# RubyMine: Duplicity lines on steps.rb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rubymine

I have two files `.feature` and both are about diferent feature on my system.
Feature **A** is about Login and Feature **B** is about Register.
However in both files contains:

```
And(/^I click on button "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
    pending
end
```

When I create the `steps.rb` one for each `.feature`, it is accusses duplicity, but the buttons are completely different.

Is there a way to implement two different clicks on the same file `step.rb` to the same line?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different scenarios and pass the button's element id inside the double quotes?

`I click on button "Login"`

`I click on button "Login1"`

You can have one step definitions and invoke multiple gherkin steps with this way

Creating two step definitions steps for each scenario will lead to duplication when the rubymine tries to auto populate the gherkin steps used.